# batch script run command if available memory less than X mb

Tags: command-line, memory, batch-jobs

I would like write a batch script that checks used or available memory allow me to run commands if available memory less than X mb.

I googled but page they refer didn't work for me I am using centos 7

basically I would like to do

```
if availablememory < 26000m
do command=forever stopall
do command=pkill -f checkurl.php
end 






BEFORE PROGRAM START
[root@www ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32002        3471         802        1121       27728       26529
Swap:         38112         234       37878
[root@www ~]#


AFTER PROGRAM START 
[root@www ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32002       13913         200        1121       17887       16381
Swap:         38112         234       37878
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [ $(awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { print $2; }' /proc/meminfo) -lt 123456 ]; then
    : do someting
done
```

Comment: I use this command as follow
 #!/bin/bash
if [ $(awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { print $2; }' /proc/meminfo) -lt 15000 ];
then
    echo "less than 15000"
else
    echo "greater than 15000"
fi
--------------------------------------------------------
available memory is now 12500  result is  
"greater than 15000"
where I did wrong ?

Comment: you don't need to exit awk for that 

 $   awk  '/^MemAvailable:/ { if ($2 < 12345)  { print "less"} else { print "more" } }'  /proc/meminfo

Comment: @DiegoRoccia I did your solution but I don't know it gives me error message -------------- checkmemory: line 1: /^MemAvailable:/ { if ($2 < 12345) { print "less"} else { print "more" } }: No such file or directory

Comment: I think you're missing the filename /proc/meminfo at the end of the command.

Comment: @danone The output of `awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { print $2; }' /proc/meminfo` is `12500`? You could execute `set -x` before in order to see what the shell does.

Comment: @DiegoRoccia
[root@www ~]# $awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { if ($2 < 12345) { print "less"} else { print "more" } }' /proc/meminfo
-bash: /^MemAvailable:/ { if ($2 < 12345) { print "less"} else { print "more" } }: No such file or directory

Comment: @HaukeLaging
[root@www ~]# awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { print $2; }' /proc/meminfo
11860808

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes I now understand I should use kbytes not mb thank you .

Comment: #!/bin/bash
if [ $(awk '/^MemAvailable:/ { print $2; }' /proc/meminfo) -lt 27000000 ];
 then
echo "free memory less than 27 gb do nothing"
 else
echo "free memory greater than 27gb kill forever and deletesearch"
pkill -f filter_delete.php
forever stopall
fi